# IconLayer in deck.gl not staying anchored to specific latitude/longitude when navigating a 3D map

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, google-map-tiles-api

I am currently using deck.gl to render a 3D map using Tile3DLayer. Additionally, I am using an IconLayer to overlay an icon on the map. My expectation is for the icon to remain anchored to a specific building when I navigate the map.

However, when I pan or zoom, the icon does not move along with the 3D layer. It seems like it's not staying at the same longitude and latitude when the map moves. It's as if the IconLayer doesn't take the 3D transformations of the Tile3DLayer into account.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import { GeoJsonLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';
import { Tile3DLayer } from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';
import { DataFilterExtension, _TerrainExtension as TerrainExtension } from '@deck.gl/extensions';
import { IconLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';

const ICON_MAPPING = {
    marker: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 128, mask: false }
};

const ICON_ATLAS = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/icon-atlas.png';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBYchwzbcKzBDjxrSAEcxOCcDWLQKD5FAx4s'; // eslint-disable-line
const TILESET_URL = 'https://tile.googleapis.com/v1/3dtiles/root.json';
export const COLORS = [
    [254, 235, 226],
    [251, 180, 185],
    [247, 104, 161],
    [197, 27, 138],
    [122, 1, 119]
];
const colorScale = scaleLinear().clamp(true).domain([0, 50, 100, 200, 300]).range(COLORS);
const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
    latitude: 48.8681586,
    longitude: 2.30278,
    zoom: 16,
    minZoom: 14,
    maxZoom: 16.5,
    bearing: 90,
    pitch: 60
};
const BUILDING_DATA =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/google-3d-tiles/buildings.geojson';
export default function App({ data = TILESET_URL, distance = 0, opacity = 0.2 }) {
    const [credits, setCredits] = useState('');
    const iconLayer = new IconLayer({
        id: 'icon-layer',
        data: [{
            coordinates: [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.longitude, INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.latitude],
            icon: 'marker'
        }],
        pickable: true,
        iconAtlas: ICON_ATLAS,
        iconMapping: ICON_MAPPING,
        getIcon: d => d.icon,
        getSize: 60,
        sizeScale: 0.5,
        getPosition: d => d.coordinates,
        getColor: [255, 0, 0, 255],
        getAngle: 0,
        billboard: true,
        zIndex: 10,
        parameters: {
            depthTest: false
        }
    })
    const layers = [
        new Tile3DLayer({
            id: 'google-3d-tiles',
            data: TILESET_URL,
            onTilesetLoad: tileset3d => {

                tileset3d.options.onTraversalComplete = selectedTiles => {
                    const uniqueCredits = new Set();
                    selectedTiles.forEach(tile => {
                        const { copyright } = tile.content.gltf.asset;
                        copyright.split(';').forEach(uniqueCredits.add, uniqueCredits);
                    });
                    setCredits([...uniqueCredits].join('; '));
                    return selectedTiles;
                };
            },
            loadOptions: {
                fetch: { headers: { 'X-GOOG-API-KEY': GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY } }
            },
            operation: 'terrain+draw'
        }),
        new GeoJsonLayer({
            id: 'buildings',
            data: BUILDING_DATA,
            extensions: [new DataFilterExtension({ filterSize: 1 }), new TerrainExtension()],
            stroked: false,
            filled: true,
            getFillColor: ({ properties }) => colorScale(properties.distance_to_nearest_tree),
            opacity,
            getFilterValue: f => f.properties.distance_to_nearest_tree,
            filterRange: [distance, 500]
        }),
        iconLayer

    ];
    return (
        <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '300px', height: '300px', margin: 'auto' }}>
            <DeckGL
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#061714' }}
                initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
                controller={{ touchRotate: true, inertia: 250 }}
                layers={layers}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Key points:

I've set billboard: true on the IconLayer, which should make the icon always face the camera.
The icon is placed at [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.longitude, INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.latitude].
Has anyone faced a similar issue? How can I ensure the icon remains at the exact geographic coordinate, even when navigating the 3D map?